# Access Serial Port on Remote System

Tags: linux

Is there a nifty emacs command to access the serial port on a remote system?;)

I've seen socat, which creates a virtual serial port on the local system, but if emacs can do it directly, without that, I'd like to know.

Comment: Can you use tramp to login to the remote machine and from there run a shell command to access the serial port?  Tramp will then magically send the output to an Emacs buffer.  Alternatively you could try using `M-x term`, log into the remote machine and then run minicom,  but personally I've never got on very well with Emacs' terminal support...